# ROBLOX - Why isn't my while loop working?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to grow berries on a tree but it's not working

```
local berries = {}
local growTime = 3
local grew = false

while grew == false do
    wait(growTime)

    for i = 1, 3, 1 do
        local berry = Instance.new("Part")
        berry.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
        berry.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really red")
    end
    grew = true
end
```

It doesn't even run, what's wrong? The script is on a localScript(child of a tree, and the tree is a child of the workspace area)

Answer (score 0):

Well you first need to understand code structure. There exist Scripts (for the server), LocalScripts (for the client), and ModuleScripts (to import from either).

ModuleScripts can exist anywhere, because they only exist to be imported by a Script or LocalScript. LocalScripts can only exist in a few places, and Workspace is not one of them, unless parented to a player’s character. Off the top of my head, they can only exist in the following places:

- ReplicatedFirst
- StarterCharacterScripts (replicated into the player’s character in Workspace)
- StarterPlayerScripts
- StarterGui

In your case, you’d want to use a regular Script. If you want it to occur only on the client, you’d want to put your LocalScript in any of those places (although, StarterPlayerScripts would be best practice for this scenario)

See: https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/scripts